# MySQL - Get results that don't match

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a query that will return all rows that's not like a query.

I just cant get it to work.

The query is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  EmailHistory
WHERE Subject not like
(
SELECT Date, Subject, Sender, Checks.Check FROM EmailHistory JOIN Checks ON EmailHistory.Subject LIKE CONCAT(  '%', Checks.Check,  '%' )
)
```

So basically I want to get all rows from EmailHistory, that I do not get when running:

```
SELECT Date, Subject, Sender, Checks.Check FROM EmailHistory JOIN Checks ON EmailHistory.Subject LIKE CONCAT(  '%', Checks.Check,  '%' )
```

I get the following error when I try to run the query: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

The query

```
SELECT Date, Subject, Sender, Checks.Check FROM EmailHistory JOIN Checks ON EmailHistory.Subject LIKE CONCAT(  '%', Checks.Check,  '%' )
```

is working as it should, I get query of all queries where the subject matches the fields that I check from the table `Checks`.

Comment: you can't return more than one field in the sub-select... how should mysql compare 5 fields agains 1 field?
use WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field .. WHERE ..)

Comment: Like if for match a substring inside a string not for scan table and column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use LIKE to match with a table. The nested query returns a table with multi columns.

You are trying to match the column '**Subject**' with a table.

The query you need is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  EmailHistory
WHERE Subject NOT IN
(
SELECT Subject FROM EmailHistory JOIN Checks ON EmailHistory.Subject LIKE CONCAT(  '%', Checks.Check,  '%' )
)
```